# Angular2 server connect

Tags: angular

I am following angular.io tutorial in order to learn angular2.
I have followed its steps.

created

```
package.json
systemjs.config.js
tsconfig.ts
typings.json
```

files

creates app.components.ts

```
import { component } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
    selector:'my-app',
    template:'<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
});

export class AppComponent{}
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Appcomponent } from './app.components';

bootstrap(Appcomponent);
```

and finally index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

yet while using `npm start` to start it the console just throws errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/app/main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:16 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js(…)(anonymous function) @ localhost/:16
3content.js:191 NO OEMBED
http://localhost:3000/styles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

is there any build in server? Tutorial does not show any server set up . Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

thanks

Comment: Just to be sure: You did install all node modules with `npm install` , before running `npm start`, right?

Comment: @ErikvandeVen yes i did

Comment: Created the styles.css also? Because it returns a 404 on that file as well.

Comment: @ErikvandeVen Yep i did

Comment: take a look at @Sajads answer. And at this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html the part about Naming conventions. For example `import { component } from '@angular/core'` should be `import { Component } from '@angular/core'` with capital C

Answer (score 0):

change folder name "app.components.ts" to "app.component.ts" and inside main.ts change "Appcomponent" to "AppComponent". it should be written CamelCase

Comment: same result as before

Comment: change this as well. "from './app.components'" to " from './app.component '"